# Single calculation for objective function and constraints function in fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, differential-equations

In my program I need to solve a Boundary Value Problem in the optimization routine which also has non linear constraints. Using `fmincon` for the problem and i need the solution of the  `BVP` to evaluate the objective function and the non linear constraint function.

Currently I am solving the BVP in objective function and also in constraint function. Is there a more efficient way in which after one evaluation of the BVP in objective function, I can pass the solution to the constraint function in order to reduce one more BVP evaluation. Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single function with an extra input, which you use to discriminate between the two calls. This is basically a wrapper around the objective and constraint functions, saving all necessary intermediate output in `persistent` variables:

```
function varargout = my_obj_con_function(..., option)

    persistent C, Ceq; % ... or any other data you might need

    switch (option)

        case 'obj'

            % objective function 
            [varargout{1}, data] = objfun(...); % 'data' is an example

            % constraint function 
            [C, Ceq] = confcn(data, ...);

        case 'con'

            % You've just computed this -- just return it
            varargout{1} = C;
            varargout{2} = Ceq;
            return 

    end

end
```

Use like this:

```
[...] = fmincon(@(x) my_obj_con_function(x, ..., 'obj'), ...
                x0,...
                Lb, Ub, ...
                A, b,...
                Aeq, beq, ...
                @(x) my_obj_con_function(x, ..., 'con'), ...);
```

This explicitly assumes that `fmincon` *always* calls the constraint function *after* calling the objective function, with *exactly* the same values for the decision variables. Now I'm not sure if that can be guaranteed -- you might want to build in some protections and mechanisms around when that is not the case.

Comment: I implemented and find that optimization prematurely stops saying that constraint not satisfied and step size reached its tolerance. If I run them seperately (i.e) as told in the question, then it continues. Something is missing, I am not sure if its in the fmincon algorithm which needs to be tweaked

Comment: @qwerty123 have you checked that `fmincon` uses the same value for `x` for the evaluation of `objfcn` and the `confcn` inside the wrapper?

Comment: I am not passing x as input argument to the `confcn`. As per the pseudo code above I am only using `data` to the `confcn` which is needed for my constraint calculations. So I might have not understood 'check whether using same x in `objfcn` and `confcn` by fmincon'

Comment: @qwerty123 ah, I see. `fmincon` will usually evaluate the objective function a whole bunch of times around the current value of interest `x` in order to get its derivatives. It then proceeds to evaluate the constraint function to see if constraints are satisfied at `x`, usually also multiple times to get *its* derivatives. So it might not be so straightforward to do what you want -- you might need to store multiple copies of `data` along with the corresponding value `x`, and then later detect for *which* `x` `fmincon` is computing outputs...

Comment: @qwerty123 ...Usually, it's *a lot* easier to just live with the inefficiency of re-computing the objective function a couple of times.

Comment: Apologize if my question was not clear. So it is better to stick with inefficiency in my case (using MATLAB )

Comment: @qwerty123 well, "better", that depends on your definition of "better" :) It will almost certainly be easier, though. How long does it normally take before convergence? How often do you have to do this?

Comment: @RodyOldenhius I put a limit on iterations to around 150 and it takes 30 minutes for a single case. I haven't checked the time for convergence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132726/discussion-between-rody-oldenhuis-and-qwerty123).